# New connections are made when I navigate through different pages Socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

New connection are made each time I move through different pages on my website.

I saw somewhere that the solution for this is changing:

```
const socket=io('');
```

to

```
const socket = io('', {transports: ['websocket']});
```

However, when I do this I get an error that the connection failed to be made.

Answer (score 1):

When a user navigates to a new page in a browser, it starts over with and reestablishes all sorts of things including socket connections and DOM elements. That's the way it works.

You may wish to refactor your web code and figure out how to avoid navigating to new pages, possibly by using [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) or [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) requests to retrieve updated data.

Comment: There is no problem that it creates new socket, but the problem is that even the old ones are still.